# Android default density values when the current is missing

Tags: android, resources

I had a question about densities and how Android chooses the right `values` folder for the current density. I think I've found the answer but I am not completely sure so I'll post what I've found. At least, this post may help someone.

For example, if I only include folders `values`, `values-hdpi` and `values-xxhdpi`, what does Android do when the current density is `xhpdi`?

It seems that Android looks for a higher density folder, so it will use `values-xxhdpi`.

And what happens when the current density is `xxxhdpi`?

It seems that, if Android can't find a higher density folder, it looks for a lower one, so it will use `values-xxdpi` too.

Android will never use the default `values` folder for a value that is defined in some specific `values-*dpi` folder.

To sum up, supposing I only have `values`, `values-xxhdpi` and `values-hdpi`:

- Values in `values-hdpi` will be used for devices with densities `ldpi`, `mdpi` and `hdpi`.
- Values in `values-xxhdpi` will be used for devices with densities `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`and `xxxhdpi`.
- Values in `values` won't be ever used if they are defined in any `values-*dpi` folder.

Let me know what you think about this.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. It wasn't as apparent to me and you are right. Spent hours until I've realized this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`density` qualifier is an exception of how resource matching works.

> Screen pixel density is the one qualifier that is not eliminated due
>   to a contradiction. Even though the screen density of the device is
>   hdpi, drawable-port-ldpi/ is not eliminated because every screen
>   density is considered to be a match at this point.

[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

> when the system is looking for a density-specific resource and does
>   not find it in the density-specific directory, **it won't always use the
>   default resources. The system may instead use one of the other
>   density-specific resources** in order to provide better results when
>   scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density resource and it
>   is not available, the system prefers to scale-down the high-density
>   version of the resource, because the system can easily scale a
>   high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5, with
>   fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by a
>   factor of 0.75.

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

So in case of `density` Android may use the default folder, but may also decide to use one that is not an exact match. Of course the substantiation is about `drawable` resources, but the mechanism probably works the same also for all other resources. Otherwise there could be a problem with `drawables` not matching other resources because they were chosen using different rules.

Comment: Thanks, I see the docs aren't very specific on that. "The system may instead use one of the other density-specific resources". I suppose that's the "answer" to my question. :)

Comment: @FerranMaylinch That is probably because there are so many devices with different screen specifications that the system sometimes decides that it would be better to use some not exactly matching density folder, than the default one. And I think they don't want to precisely document this mechanism, because it is probably often changed and adjusted, so they don't want developers to rely on it.